# Is there way to only perform the doctests, ignoring print function calls?

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, doctest

Hypothetically speaking, my function *returns a value* and *has lot of print statements* (maybe 100 or more).

Is there a way to run [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) such that all the other printing work can be ignored/skipped (I am familiar with the `+SKIP` directive, which is for skipping `doctest` examples), i.e. when I execute my function (or run my module as a script) with `doctest`s:

```
python mymodule.py
```

Or:

```
python -m doctest mymodule.py
```

I should get:

- nothing, in case of success; or
- error messages in case any test example fails;

and nothing else. Running `doctest` should not give me a terminal window full of outputs / text from those `print` function calls.

Please don't suggest using unit testing (e.g. [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html)) as it'll kill the essence of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`doctest` uses `stdout`, **not** `stderr`, to show messages from any failing tests. Therefore you cannot patch out `stdout` as this answer originally suggested - this will suppress your `print` calls **and** any messages from `doctest`.

---

One option is to define functions that `print` with an additional `verbose` parameter, so that you can suppress this when necessary.

```
def foo(verbose=True):
    """Does whatever.

        >>> foo(verbose=False)

    """
    if verbose:
        print('Hello world')
```

Although you have to change the functions, this also gives you useful options when not testing.

---

Another is to explicitly supply the appropriate `print` function to the functions that use it, allowing you to pass a NOOP at runtime:

```
def bar(print=print):
    """Does whatever.

        >>> bar(print=lambda *args, **kwargs: None)

    """
    print('Hello world')
```

This also requires changes to function definitions, but at least avoids changes in the *bodies* of those functions.

---

A third option is to patch out `print` for the whole module under test, for example:

```
def baz():
    """Does whatever.

        >>> baz()

    """
    print('Hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import doctest

    print = lambda *args, **kwargs: None

    doctest.testmod()
```

Note that this affects the outputs that `doctest` sees, too, so you don't include any of the `print` output in the docstring (I assume this is good news!) It won't work with `python -m doctest mymodule.py`, though.

Comment: very good. for that last case, how about `COMMAND = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))[0]; print = (lambda *args, **kwargs: None) if COMMAND == 'doctest' else print` ... ?

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx I'd guard the reassignment rather than use a ternary expression, but that would work if you need that edge case.

Comment: yeah I would too if I weren't trying to type it in a comment box :smile:

Answer (score 1):

in addition to [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)'s excellent answer, there is one more way, that *does* work with the `python3 -m doctest module.py` construct.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 -OO
'''
Some ideas for adding additional verbosity during doctest, and for
reducing verbosity and startup delays during doctest or pydoc.
'''
from __future__ import print_function  # for compatibility with python2
import sys, os, logging
logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG if __debug__ else logging.INFO)
COMMAND = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))[0]
if COMMAND in ['doctest', 'pydoc']:
    NONDOCTESTPRINT = lambda *args, **kwargs: None
    DOCTESTDEBUG = logging.debug
else:
    NONDOCTESTPRINT = print
    DOCTESTDEBUG = lambda *args, **kwargs: None
    # You can also use this `else` block to import things not needed during
    # doctest, especially slow-loading modules like `requests`,
    # or to do some other verbose or slow initialization.

def test(string):
    '''
    print string after lead-in

    >>> test("I'm in love with you!")
    Listen!
    I'm in love with you!
    '''
    DOCTESTDEBUG("If this works, you shouldn't see anything but this")
    print('Listen!')
    NONDOCTESTPRINT('Do you want to know a secret?')
    NONDOCTESTPRINT('Do you promise not to tell? Whoa, oh...')
    NONDOCTESTPRINT('Closer...')
    NONDOCTESTPRINT('Let me whisper in your ear...')
    NONDOCTESTPRINT('Say the words you long to hear...')
    print(string)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test(' '.join(sys.argv[1:]) or 'Taxation is theft.')
```

Here is what the output looks like, depending on how it's called.

```
jcomeau@aspire:/tmp$ python3 -m doctest doctesttest.py 
DEBUG:root:If this works, you shouldn't see anything but this
jcomeau@aspire:/tmp$ python3 doctesttest.py This is a test!
Listen!
Do you want to know a secret?
Do you promise not to tell? Whoa, oh...
Closer...
Let me whisper in your ear...
Say the words you long to hear...
This is a test!
```

and for `pydoc doctesttest`:

[image: pydoc output of above script]

Comment: 'Taxation is theft.' is politics, should be pop songs or Monty Python references. Since you were looking to be discovered.