# Show result of print function calls in doc-tests

Tags: python, doctest

I am debugging the failure of a doc-test. I debug with `print()` statements instead of emulators and breakpoints. Doc-tests seem to suppress the `stdout` of the functions under test.

[Is there way to only perform the doctests, ignoring print function calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696944/is-there-way-to-only-perform-the-doctests-ignoring-print-function-calls) mentions the opposite, how to suppress print function calls. The behavior seems to have changed in Python3.

One clumsy solution is to copy the body of the doc-test to `main()`, remove the leading angled brackets, debug, copy back, and iterate. It'd be easier to keep the function in the doc-test.

This command prints extended output from the doctest but not from the functions under test:

```
python3 -m doctest -v module.py
```

How can I include the output of print function calls of the functions under test?

### Update

Here is a minimal example of a doc-test.

```
import doctest

def sum(a, b):
    """
    >>> 2 == sum(1, 1)
    True
    >>> n = sum(1, 1)
    >>> 2 == n
    True
    """

    print("Hello world")
    return False  # anything to break the test


doctest.testmod(optionflags=doctest.ELLIPSIS)
```

The result is:

```
**********************************************************************
Failed example:
    2 == sum(1, 1)
Expected:
    True
Got:
    Hello world
    False
**********************************************************************
Failed example:
    n = sum(1, 1)
Expected nothing
Got:
    Hello world
**********************************************************************
Failed example:
    2 == n
Expected:
    True
Got:
    False
**********************************************************************
```

So the code works as expected, and the problem lies in writing the tests to fit the doctest framework of matching expected and actual print output. I usually assign the function call to a variable and test that variable, so the prints come not in the test failure but in the function call (which I normally catch with an ellipsis, even though I don't do it here). One solution is to hide print output for doc-tests and to turn it back on when I need to debug.

Comment: Do you have a sample of a doctest you're running? I get the output from all failed tests.

Comment: I added details and realized that the problem is not what I stated. Can you post an answer, maybe taken from my update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write debugging output to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.

```
import sys
# for debug statements
print('debugging stuff', file=sys.stderr)
```